# android connection httpURLConnection code 0

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I have this Java code and run it on Android emulator:

It gives an error on: *connection "0" and more not have access request on server*.

i try url with web browser on emulator and work well, but not with app.

```
    public class Recipe extends ActionBarActivity  {
        TextView tex;
        Button but;
        String URL ="http://10.0.2.2/my_prog/www/mango/android/publico.php";
        HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        InputStream is =null;
        int response;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.recipe);

         but=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
         tex=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    int len = 500; 
                    try{
                        String Url = "http://10.0.2.2/my_prog/www/mango/android/publico.php";                                        

                        URL url = new URL(Url);
                        HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                        conn.setDoInput(true);
                        conn.connect();
                        response = conn.getResponseCode();
                        is = conn.getInputStream();

                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                        StringBuffer sb =new StringBuffer();
                        String line="";
                        while ((line =br.readLine()) != null){
                            sb.append(line);                                
                        }
                        String data = sb.toString();
                        tex.setText(data);

                    }
catch(Exception ex){
                        tex.setText("problema di connetion" + response);    
                    }                       
                }

            private String readIt(InputStream is, int len) {
                Reader reader= null;
                try{
                reader =new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
                char[] buffer =new char[len];
                reader.read(buffer);
                return new String(buffer);
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    return new String("problem on convert");    
                }
            }            
            });  
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Comment: don't forget to add Internet permission in you android manifest
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: of course i give the internet permission on my app,thanks for your idea but isn it

Comment: You shouldn't do http connection in main thread, it should be done in background thread

Comment: thanks for your contrib,,i take your point have some easy example

Comment: in strict mode (from android 4.0) strict mode is default, so your code will not work without put the http connection in background thread

Comment: you comment is right ,i changed somethingh on code and now work well..thanks a lot